# Leave only last event name for each user (r language)

Tags: r

I have a table(input):

```
user_id  timestamp  progression

1 Rob     22223333   Level1
2 Mike    33334444   Level2
3 Rob     55558888   Level3
4 Mike    44447777   Level7
```

I need to add column with last `progression` which depends on `timestamp`.

Desired output:

```
user_id  timestamp  progression lastProgression

1 Rob     22223333   Level1     Level3
2 Mike    33334444   Level2     Level7
3 Rob     55558888   Level3     Level3
4 Mike    44447777   Level7     Level7
```

Comment: There is probably no need for an external package here, but I would go with `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[unique(df[order(-timestamp)], by = "user_id"), lastProgression := i.progression, on = "user_id"]` for efficiency

Comment: Or `setDT(df)[, lastProgression := progression[which.max(timestamp)], by = user_id]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ave` from `base R`, we can select the last one observation (`tail(x, 1)`) after grouping by 'user_id' (assuming that the 'timestamp') is ordered earlier.

```
df1$lastProgression <- with(df1, ave(progression, user_id, FUN= function(x) tail(x,1)))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  arrange(desc(timestamp)) %>% 
  mutate(lastProgression = first(progression))
```

or a modified option using `which.max` (from @docendo discimus comments)

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(user_id) %>%
   mutate(lastProgression =  progression[which.max(timestamp)])
```

Comment: I understood the question to depend on `timestamp`, i.e. it's not necessarily the last entry (but may be wrong)

Comment: @docendodiscimus I updated with a `dplyr` option where it gets ordered to select the `first` value.

Comment: Since `timestamp` is a numeric/integer variable, I think you could also use `group_by(df1, user_id) %>% mutate(lastProgression = progression[which.max(timestamp)])`